# how to see the raw email body BEFORE send it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email-template, triggered-send

I know we can use the "Send Preview" but this is not resolving my issue.

The email is dynamically conformed. So I use the API

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:$extKey/send

To send it.

Is there any other way to get the email BEFORE is being sent, I mean to get the email in RAW format before MarketingCloud send it???

If I send the email using the "Send Preview code" and use putsmail.com I got well conformed in mailinator.com

However If I use the API to send it ... it's missing a link button. But it only happens in mailinator.com

If I use hotmail.com yahoo.com or gmail.com... It's perfect. Despite I use putsmail.com or the API to send the email.

Somebody has experienced the same issue?